# My code always returns error function in ajax but data reaches database

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My code always returns error function in Ajax, but data reaches database

My ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sub").click(function c() {
        var datax = $("#text").val();

        var dat = datax.toString();
        alert(dat);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"commentering",
            data: dat,
            success: function (da) {
                alert(da);

                var a = $("<input type='text'>").val(da);

                $("#body").append(a);
            },

            error: function (error) {
                alert('error; ' + eval(error));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult commentering(FormCollection f)
    {

        Random rad = new Random();
        comment c = new comment();
        c.id = rad.Next(15151);

        c.comments = f.Get(0).ToString();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.comments.Add(c);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(c.comments);
        }
        return Json("errorx");

    }
```

It calls the controller but still does not execute successfully. It worked once but now it causes an error.

Comment: Is `#sub` a submit button? What is the selector for your `form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, your jQuery code should be as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"commentering",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(da) {
                alert(da);                    
                var a = $("<input type='text'/>").val(da);                    
                $("body").append(a);
            },                
            error: function(x, s, e) {
                alert('error: ' + s + ' -- ' + e);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help but new textbox is not showing up although alert(da) gets executed and database also gets data

Comment: Great! Do you have an element with id=body or did you just want to append the text box to the body element.

Comment: well testbox was showing but it was at below I made to come at top thanks for help

Comment: Pleasure was all mine! Glad I could be of help :)